# How to make a CSS element extend beyond all borders of containing div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JS Fiddle going of something that I am trying to do here. As you can see I have a circle sitting in the center of a div. When you run the script it expends evenly in all directions until it hits the left and top of the screen. What I want to happen is the circle to expand evenly in all directions (through all of the containing divs borders) so that it fills the screen with red, but I am at a loss on how to get it to overflow left and top.

here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dkarasinski/UxtJV/711/

```
HTML

<div class="outerwrapper">
    <div class="test">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>

jquery

$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
$('.circle').addClass('open');
}, 2000);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't need JS to trigger your transform you know? CSS3 can handle it all for  you. Even with a nice *zoom* animation. Explore CSS3 animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're explicitly putting the `<div>` at `(0, 0)` on the page.

Instead of trying to figure out the position, you can just take advantage of the `transform` property:

```
div.open {
    transform: scale(50, 50);
}
```

That makes the circle 50 times bigger in both the X and Y axes. The element won't change position; it'll just get bigger.

Comment: You put it a damn site better than I did @Pointy! (fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ghopkins/sLpz7eoq/)

Comment: @GarethHopkins well yours will work too, and it doesn't rely on browsers supporting `transform` (though it already relies on `border-radius` so ...

Comment: poinby - I like that but the edges are so jagged is there a way to have them smoothed out?
@GarethHopkins - I asked above but I will just add it to this thread. Ideally I would like ti to start and stay in the middle of the page for the animation - http://jsfiddle.net/dkarasinski/UxtJV/711/

Comment: @GrooveChampion ?? I don't see any jagged edges; you mean while it's animating? Probably depends on the browser ... I'll check Chrome.

Comment: @GrooveChampion as per-request if you want to fill your screen with red, your last concern are the edges. Sorry to remind you but it's stated in your question: *`"...so that it fills the screen with red."`*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Didn't mean to offend, Sorry. I want to be a proper member of this community, new here, didn't mean anything by it. Anyway, these are all great solutions. Thank you, with a little tinkering I can definitely get this to where I want it to be, thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys!

Comment: (OT) @GrooveChampion :) kind from you! Don't worry, I never get offended (I adore constructive criticism) and I can assure you the same for almost every other (10000+) user I know on this site! We strive to give the most accurate answers but we expect the same from Questions! Warm welcome to SO and see you around! Happy coding and hope to see some nice answers of yours! GL

Answer (score 3):

I think it's more to do with your top and left absolute on the .open css class style.

Here's a fork of your fiddle with -200px on both top and left: http://jsfiddle.net/ghopkins/3eybkrz1/

Change in code:

```
div.open {
 top: -200px;
 left: -200px;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 1000px; 
}
```

Your version is pinning the top left 'corner' of the circle and expanding down and right.

Comment: Hmmm, is there a way to make it keep its central position and then still end up beyond the top and left borders?  http://jsfiddle.net/dkarasinski/UxtJV/711/

Comment: @GrooveChampion yes, using `scale()` (or with just a bit of math and imagination like margin-left/top: -value; combined with W/H incrementation)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

`transform: translate(-25%, -25%);`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/UxtJV/714/